# Casting with C# source code in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a custom C# method in a PowerShell script I am writing. The goal of the function is to figure out if a certain line exists in a file. Here is my source:

```
$source = @"
using System;

public class Differ
{
    public static bool isInFile(Array file, String line)
    {
        foreach(string curLine in file)
        {
            if(curLine.Replace(" ", "") == line.Replace(" ", ""))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source

$file1 = Get-Content "path\to\file"
$file2 = Get-Content "path\to\file"

$diff = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

$lineNumber = 0
$file1 | foreach {
[String]$theLine = $_

    if ([Differ]::isInFile([Array]$file2, [String]$theLine) -eq $false -and -not [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($theLine)) {
        $diff.Add($lineNumber, $_.ToString().Trim())
    }

    $lineNumber++
}

$diffHeader =  @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Line"}, `
@{Expression={$_.Value};Label="Content"}

$diff | Sort-Object Line | Format-Table $diffHeader -AutoSize
```

It gives me the following error when I run the script:

```
Exception calling "isInFile" with "2" argument(s): "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.String'."
At C:\Users\jcarl\Dropbox\PowerShell\compare_config\comapre.ps1:33 char:9
+     if ([Differ]::isInFile([Array]$file2, [String]$theLine) -eq $false) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastException
```

I am guessing that it is erroring on the second object I am trying to pass in to isInFile, but I am not sure. I have verified that PowerShell loads both files into their variables correctly and that there is a string in the $theLine variable.

Comment: When you do a `$theLine|GM` does it say that the object type is `System.String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function declaration is wrong. You need to use `string[]` instead of `Array`. Replace:

```
public static bool isInFile(Array file, String line)
```

with

```
public static bool isInFile(string[] file, String line)
```

And the casts in the PS code([string] and [array]) are unnecessary.

Personally, I would just skip the c# and use the built-in powershell operators like this. It's cleaner. I prefer to only load C#-code if I need to shave off as many nanoseconds as possible, but then again, a compiled application would be better for that :-) Try this:

```
$file1 = Get-Content "path\to\file"
$file2 = Get-Content "path\to\file" 

$diff = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

$lineNumber = 0
$trimmedfile2 = $file2 | % { $_ -replace " " }

$file1 | foreach {

    if($trimmedfile2 -notcontains ($_ -replace " ") -and -not [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) {
        $diff.Add($lineNumber, $_.Trim())
    }

    $lineNumber++
}

$diffHeader =  @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Line"}, @{Expression={$_.Value};Label="Content"}

$diff | Sort-Object Line | Format-Table $diffHeader -AutoSize
```